# Javascript regex for validation of a text box

Tags: javascript, regex

When a user type a text,i want to allow alpha numeric + space + min three characters + smileys should be there.This is the regex ,m using but it is not validation

```
   /^([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,})$/
```

Comment: "+ smileys"? What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{3,}|:P|:)$

- I space was added to the character class
- Alternation (|) was used to allow the 2 smiley's you mentioned

This regex will match the following 3 string

just some text
:)
:P

Let use know if you want to include other matches, fe a line with a smiley and some more text

Regards, Tom

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
/^(?=.{3,})[a-zA-Z0-9 :;()]+$/
```

**explanation:**

```
/                    : delimiter
  ^                  : begining of string
  (?=.{3,})          : assure there are at least 3 chars
  [a-zA-Z0-9 :;()]+  : assure there are only allowed char
  $                  : end of string
/                    : delimiter
```

You can add all the characters you want to be allowed in the char class.